Given the eccentricity of two traces of a quadric surface, what can be said about the eccentricity of the third?
Traces of quadric surfaces are conic sections.  All traces in parallel planes have the same eccentricity.
Given a quadric surface $S$ with eccentricity $\varepsilon_x$ in the $x$-plane and $\varepsilon_y$ in the $y$-plane, what can be said about the eccentricity $\varepsilon_z$ in the $z$-plane?
Note that I am defining the $x,y,z$ planes as defined in this question.

Conjecture
First, we need to exclude the cylinders, since their traces don't have a defined eccentricity.
Based on examining all of the quadric surfaces, I conjecture the following:

Suppose none of the eccentricities equal unity.  Then we can pick any values in the range $[0, 1) \cup (1, \infty)$ for $\varepsilon_x$ and $\varepsilon_y$, and these will uniquely determine $\varepsilon_z$.
If $\varepsilon_x = 1$, then either $\varepsilon_y$ or $\varepsilon_z$ must equal $1$ as well; the other can take on any value in the range $[0, \infty)$
Knowing the three eccentricities determines the quadric (up to similarity) only with some other information:


For cases when two eccentricities are greater than $1$, we need to introduce a new parameter, which determines how far apart the sheets are: 2-sheets, a cone, or 1-sheet (with a cone being a limiting case between 2 and 1 sheet)

Thus:

If one eccentricity is $1$, at least another eccentricity must be $1$, and the third can be any value in $[0, \infty)$
Otherwise, any two eccentricities can be chosen, and the third is then determined
In cases where two of the eccentricities are $> 1$, we need another parameter to describe the surface: this parameter continuously deforms a hyperboloid of 2 sheets into a cone into a hyperboloid of 1 sheet


See this 1889 document

@JeanMarie Wow.  The paper is a bit beyond me, but clearly trying to get at this.  Can you help me understand it - or perhaps present its primary conclusions (perhaps as an answer)?

I  will have a closer look at it. Not sure to build an answer...
